# I got jquery-ui sortable working with meteor templates, but is it a bad hack?

Tags: jquery-ui, meteor, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to use jquery-ui sortable with nested templates in Meteor, as follows. Here are the two templates in question:

```
<template name="activityEditor">
  {{! the main activity editor view }}
  <div class="activity-editor">
    <input type="text" name="title" class="input-xxlarge" value="{{info.title}}" placeholder="Type a title here...">
    <div class="activity-steps">
      {{#each info.steps}}
        {{>activityStepEditor}}
      {{/each}}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>



<template name="activityStepEditor">    
  {{! the container view for each step editor }}
  <div class="activity-step" data-id="{{_id}}">

    <div class="order">{{order}}</div>
    {{!....stuff...}}

  </div>
</template>
```

and the template code (using coffeescript):

```
_.extend Template.activityEditor, {

  # ...stuff...

  rendered: ->
    $(".activity-steps").sortable {
      items: '.activity-step'
      handle: '.order'
      update: ->
        stepIds = ($(el).attr('data-id') for el in $('.activity-step'))

        $('.activity-steps').empty() #this must be done in order to steps to re-render properly
        Lab.Activity.reorderSteps stepIds 



    }
    $(".activity-steps").disableSelection()

}
```

The only way I can get this code to work and properly rerender the order is by emptying the container of my sortable elements right after they update with `$('.activity-steps').empty()`. I've tried cancelling the update event and forcing a rerender by changing another variable watched in the context, but any change causes `Exception from Meteor.flush(): undefined` after which I can't rerender anything until page reload.

This seems to work, and everything rerenders great. So my question is: is there any reason why I shouldn't do this? Is there a better, standard practice way to handle the sortable that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 0):

In the near future there'll be a better way to do it, as Meteor team is developing its new rendering engine: http://**youtube.com/watch?v=ISNEhPG0wnA** 
(in this video, Avital Oliver shows exactly a way to do it without redrawing the screen: the object in the list is actually moved on all clients)

See this Meteor's Github Wiki entry for more technical info: 
http://**github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/New-Template-Engine-Preview**

While that's not officially published, if you need it right now, you could try Nazar Leush's approach: 
http://**github.com/nleush/meteor-todos-sortable-animation** 
He also published a working example here: http://**todos-dnd-animated.meteor.com**